# Show google map suggestion in a fixed div as a list and not as drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps-api-3

This is the dynamically generated ul in which google suggestions in being shown as drop down

```
   <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: -1734.72px; left: 105px; display: none; position: relative; width: 300px;">


<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
</ul>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"></ul>
```

I want to show these suggestion in a div right to the input text box .

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top:300px;
}
.ui-autocomplete li:hover {

background-color: white;
}

.ui-corner-all{
font-size:18px;
margin-top:300px;

}
```

margin doesn't seem to work though, also when I select any suggestion from list of suggestion it doesn't show up in input field.

java script code for this -- >

```
function initialize(){
//MAP
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.659,-4.714);
  var options = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  //GEOCODER
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,

    draggable: true

  });

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  initialize();

  jQuery(function() {  
    jQuery("#address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
          response(jQuery.map(results, function(item) {
            return {            
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {

        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);


        }

    });
  });



});
```

Comment: Where is your code? not the Dynamically generated one. and the code you have posted is not sufficient.

Comment: which code ? i want to grap this dynamically generated ul inside a div  .. is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And I can help you if you could reveal atleast the part of the code where you dynamically generate it. I mean show a sample of your javascript code used for this 'ul' generation.

Comment: I posted Javascript code you can have a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to you autocomplete attributes,

```
appendTo: "#someElem"
```

For you reference [API Jquery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#options)

For margin to work try,

`display:block;`

Comment: basically I want to grab all google suggestion in a dynamically generated div